# which name are allowed to use in web templates?

Tags: templates, web, themes

I'm going to use people name is in  Web Templates. Most of the templates use John Doe and I like to use other names which is allowed in web templates. Please list the all allowed name of web templates.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any name, unless it is not the name of any brand. You can even use your own name Dipendra Thapa.